# Upgrading Angular 6 to Angular 7 beta

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular7

I have existing project with Angular 6. I want it to be upgraded to version 7 beta, if it is possible, with Ivy renderer enabled.

What are the steps to do it correctly?

Comment: upgrading from LTS version to beta non-LTS... Why?

Comment: @smnbbrv I got such requirement at a job to be done. I'm also very sceptical, but what to do. There is a big need for that ivy renderer and a small app size.

Comment: Ivy renderer could be enabled in angular cli in Angular 6 without migrating to 7

Comment: Ivy renderer is not complete and not production ready.

Comment: When Angular 7 releases, Ivy renderer will still be a work in progress

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so no one helped, I will write the solution I found myself.

1. (optional) If you use NVM, you can install the latest node.js in the first place and switch to it, to avoid possible problems
2. Install the beta angular/cli in version 7, globally and locally in the project
3. In package.json replace all occurrences with the current version of your Angular (e.g. 6.1.7) with ^7.0.0-beta.5
4. npm install
5. If there are problems delete node_modules and try again npm install

If you want to be sure, that your other packages are in latest versions, you can install empty Angular 7 application somewhere else with beta angular/cli and check what changed in package.json. Unfortunately Angular team doesn't provide a tool to install desired version of Angular, but beta cli installs Angular 7 by default.

As for Ivy renderer it's not default in Angular 7 beta. I tried to manually enable it and it didn't work. It seems this project needs a lot more work to be finished yet and there's little information on the internet how to properly use it in advanced project (there are only some very simple tutorials for empty projects).

Ivy renderer status: https://is-angular-ivy-ready.firebaseapp.com/#/status
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/STATUS.md

Ivy renderer tutorial: https://blog.imaginea.com/ivy-a-look-at-the-new-render-engine-for-angular/

Comment: Yes you're right... but you didn't have to go through all this just to know that IVY is not ready yet (I upvoted you btw)..  If I were you I'd wait a bit, as others have said, they still have a long way to go. Lazy loading gets you very far, is that a way you could go now to make your initial app payload smaller?

Comment: @Spock Hey, thanks for the kind reply :) Yeah, I have no other option, but to wait. I explained that at work. Thanks for the hint about lazy loading, I will definitely check it out, if it's not making the application slower.

Comment: Now that Angular7 is in Release Candidate I don't think we'll get a production ready version of IVY with NG7. IVY will get better and have more features but not yet ready. I really think you should wait - I'm doing the same with my application. I'll upgrade to 7 but IVY is for NG8 I think.

Comment: Hi, please note that the Ivy Compiler is **almost** done, but the Ivy Runtime is still under work. Ivy can be enabled using the "enableIvy: true" angularCompilerOptions flag. If you wanna experiment with it, please do and let us know. Cheers.